# Is it useful to unit test methods where the only logic is guards?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Say I have a method like this:

```
public void OrderNewWidget(Widget widget)
{
   if ((widget.PartNumber > 0) && (widget.PartAvailable))
   {
        WigdetOrderingService.OrderNewWidgetAsync(widget.PartNumber);
   }
}
```

I have several such methods in my code (the front half to an async Web Service call).

I am debating if it is useful to get them covered with unit tests.  Yes there is logic here, but it is only guard logic.  (Meaning I make sure I have the stuff I need before I allow the web service call to happen.)

Part of me says "sure you can unit test them, but it is not worth the time" (I am on a project that is already behind schedule).

But the other side of me says, if you don't unit test them, and someone changes the Guards, then there could be problems.

But the first part of me says back, if someone changes the guards, then you are just making more work for them (because now they have to change the guards and the unit tests for the guards).

For example, if my service assumes responsibility to check for Widget availability then I may not want that guard any more.  If it is under unit test, I have to change two places now.

I see pros and cons in both ways.  So I thought I would ask what others have done.

Comment: You are not making "more work" for the maintainers. If they change logic, they must change the corresponding unit tests. That's how it works. I don't see your cons: if your unit test didn't require changing, then it wouldn't be testing anything, would it? You might as well question whether unit testing is useful at all.

Comment: This is off topic, but I would change the logic to throw an exception if the part number is 0 or less, or if the part is not available, as in my opinion it would be a bug to allow someone to call that method with a bogus widget, silently masking another problem.

Comment: @Matthew very good point. This function lies. The naming tells you it's gonna order something. And then it doesn't but you will never know, unless you apply the same logic as is inside, which iviolates DRY. In other words: if the design is changed to be more correct, this question maybe wouldn't have been asked in the first place.

Comment: `but it is not worth the time" (I am on a project that is already behind schedule).` We are software developers.  The only time we are on schedule is when we are dead :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Part of me says "sure you can unit test them, but it is not worth the time" (I am on a project that is already behind schedule).

It's three very short tests. You spent as much time asking yourself the question.

> But the other side of me says, if you don't unit test them, and someone changes the Guards, then there could be problems.

Listen to this side.

> But the first part of me says back, if someone changes the guards, then you are just making more work for them (because now they have to change the guards and the unit tests for the guards).

If your maintainer is a TDD nut, you're making it more difficult for them. Any change I make without there being a related change or addition of tests leads to my having to think hard. In fact, I would probably add the tests before I go ahead and make the change.

The first part of you is just plain wrong. Give the second part a pat on the back and stop thinking about it.

Comment: +1 for succinctness even though I wrote an answer too heh

Comment: +1. Yes, if the requirements change, the some tests will have to be adapted.

Comment: While I like what you say, I have many instances of this kind of call in my code (the front half of an async call).  So it is not just 3 unit tests.  Still, if it is the "right" way then I want to get them done.

Comment: @Vaccano: The more of them you have to write, the more logical paths you don't have tests for and the more necessary it is to write them.

Answer (score 9):

It would simplify unit testing if the guard logic and the actual ordering were separate methods.

In the `Widget` class

```
public bool IsReadyForOrdering { get { return PartNumber > 0 && PartAvailable; } }
```

or an equivalent method somewhere else

```
public bool IsWidgetReadyForOrdering(Widget widget)
{
    return widget.PartNumber > 0 && widget.PartAvailable;
}
```

The order method

```
public void OrderNewWidget(Widget widget)
{
   if (IsWidgetReadyForOrdering(widget)) {
        WigdetOrderingService.OrderNewWidgetAsync(widget.PartNumber);
   }
}
```

Now testing `IsWidgetReadyForOrdering` became easy. Don't think a long time about it any more. Test it!

Comment: Oof, stateful logic in a property.. -1 that should be a method and it should take the PartNumber, PartAvailable due to it's simplicity. Make it protected if it need not be a part of the public API but not a property.. Also I generally disagree. The guard logic inside the method is totally fine, and in my eyes better because it's such a small method you're just polluting the class to make an already small method smaller. Add it to the class in this case only if it's repetitive logic.

Comment: First, this doesn't answer the question. Second, it's untrue. You need to write three tests either way. Third, it exposes implementation details to calling code, unnecessarily.

Comment: It's clever, but I agree with the other commenters; there's no value-added here, unless `IsReadyForOrdering` is used outside of the class.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: where do you see any stateful logic in that property? In fact, the example shows how to separate the state-changing logic (OrderNewWidget) from the non-statechanging logic (ReadyForOrdering). And I am a strong believer that extracting even that small functions will improve the code, and not making it worse, as you state. So +1.

Comment: The method `OrderNewWidget` is probably in another class than `Widget`, since it has a `Widget` argument. Since the method has no return value, testing it is not obvious. You would have to inject a `WigdetOrderingService`-mock that tracks the `OrderNewWidgetAsync` call.

Comment: @DocBrown `PartNumber` and `PartAvailable` are both part of the state of the particular object therefore the process state. A stateless method would read `public bool IsWidgetReadyForOrdering(Widget widgetToCheck) { return widgetToCheck.PartNumber > 0 && widgetToCheck.PartAvailable; }` this method relies on no state, it yields a calculation based on passed on values, only dependence to the system it has is the definition of the type rather than a particular instance of the type. That said a stateful method is idiomatic and fine. I just don't like logic more less stateful logic in a property

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: actually, your definition of "stateless" means "static" in C#. Thus, what you say is "properties should not access state of an object". But even dumb getters access state variables, so that would mean "write only static properties" - which does not seem to make much sense.

Comment: @DocBrown I was simply referring to stateful logic, I recognize the purpose of a property to access state, but to commit logic upon that state seems like a bad habit to me as there can be side effects upon the property which could violate POLA, though for a method you may expect side effects to alter the results. Also yes it's true that stateless behaviour can have the static keyword added to it if you so wish but static methods aren't always stateless, think about a static singleton's GetInstance() accessing global state. If that global state is in error it can side effect that method.

Comment: @DocBrown it's a matter of what you're consumer knows and can then reason about when using your API. If you have a stateful method it may access and have it's results dependent upon a variety of things which your consumers don't know about, and therefore it's non-obvious to them how to effect it to get the results they want. If however your method takes a widget, your consumer knows the logic somehow relies on that widget, unfortunately C# gives no guarantees  other state wasn't used also but at the least you are notifying your consumer in a clear and obvious way that its calculated on widget

Comment: Another upvote for breaking it up.  The more you can decompose your logic like this the easier it becomes to see bugs.  IsReadyForOrdering is easy to test and there's much less reason to test the one that requires mocking games.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: I see your point of  stateful-logic-less properties. It may not apply here, but when binding an object to a view you can do so only via properties. Therefore I have a lot of stateful/logicful properties. With MVC they have to be in the model, with MVVM/MVP they are in the viewmodel/presenter.

Comment: Ah yes, I've run into that before it feels like code smell but I've done the same thing, one unfortunate pain with wpf's constraints.

Comment: +1 extracting complicated checks into easy to understand method that returns boolean reminds of [Specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern), the trick that worked very well to me many times. (I am not quite comfortable about declaring IsReadyForOrdering `public` though, because I don't understand why this could be necessary)

Comment: Sometimes it is just necessary to declare things `public` for testing. There is, however, the possibility to declare it `internal` and to specify the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` and to make the internals of the current assembly visible to a test assembly.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I see thanks. Why did you use public instead of internal in your answer?

Comment: @gnat: It's up to you. If you don't have the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` testing won't work with `internal`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have time in your schedule for unit testing but you have time put aside for solid QA usage, then ask if you can steal some of that QA time to write unit tests, or if you can spend some of the QA period doing unit tests, or perhaps just deal with non-unit tested code.. Unfortunately schedules that are immovable force you to make concessions or work yourself to death, I generally suggest the first option because the second one will result in you incapable of supporting/maintaining the system correctly for the term of it.

That said, to your general question of testing guard statements; Yes! Absolutely test guard statements! Those are important parts of the behaviour of that method, you wouldn't want to find out somebody misunderstood something doing a bug-fix and removed your guards or changed the `&&` to an `||` would you? Unit tests will ensure that a) you actually got the logic on your guards correct and b) nobody breaks that logic later without getting a complaint when they run the unit tests telling them it should be that way for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

There are some excellent answers above, and the points they make are very important. But one that seems to have been missed is that of you have a comprehensive set of unit tests, they read like an extremely detailed specification of the code. If you omit testing validation just because the code is so easy it's hard to see how it could go wrong, part of your specification is missing. If I came into a team where these tests had been missed out, I would actually assume your service wasn't validating its arguments.

Answer (score -5):

Code is code. You should try to get 100% coverage when testing. If it weren't important it wouldn't be there.